# Why changes made to a @Published variable do not affect the while-loop condition?

Tags: swift

### Description

I have two classes, one of them is implemented using the singleton pattern:

```swift
class Singleton: ObservableObject {
    static let sharedSingleton = Singleton()
    private init() {}
    
    @Published var fetchingData = true

    // This is called upon launching the app
    func getData() {
        fetchingData = true
        someNetworkingCalls {
          ... // fetching data from a db
          self.fetchingData = false
        }
    }
}
```

Then, I have another class that has a function where a while-loop is used to pause the code execution if the `Singleton` class is fetching data:

```swift
class AnotherClass: ObservableObject {
    private var sharedSingleton = Singleton.sharedSingleton
    func getAnotherData() {
        while (sharedSingleton.fetchingData){// do nothing here}
        
        // then proceed execute another networking call

    }
}
```

Functions from both classes are being called in MainAppView in the following fashion:

```swift
@ObservedObject singleton = Singleton.sharedSingleton
@StateObject anotherClass = AnotherClass()
...
SomeView()
 .task {
     singleton.getData()
     anotherClass.getAnotherData()
  }
  .environmentObject(anotherClass)
...
```

### Problem

The while-loop never terminates even though I'm sure the `fetchingData` has been set to `false`.

I could mitigate this problem by wrapping `anotherClass.getAnotherData()` in an `asyncAfter` but I highly suspect that it worked only because by the time `getAnotherData()` is called, the `singleton.getData()` has already finished its job -- this could be very tricky if users have unstable/slow network connections.

I was wondering why the while-loop cannot catch the change made to the `@Published` var? And how to properly solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `while` loop is not a reliable way to wait for data to be loaded. Instead, one solution would be to use `Combine` to watch for changes to the `fetchingData` `Publisher`.

That might look like this:

```
import Combine

class AnotherClass: ObservableObject {
    private var sharedSingleton = Singleton.sharedSingleton
    
    private var cancellable : AnyCancellable?
    
    func getAnotherData() {
        cancellable = sharedSingleton.$fetchingData.sink { value in
            guard value else { return }
            //do your next action here
        }
    }
}
```

Realistically, it would be better to watch whatever the data itself is, rather than setting up a separate `fetchingData`. That might look like this:

```
class Singleton: ObservableObject {
    static let sharedSingleton = Singleton()
    private init() {}
    
    @Published var data : Data? = nil

    // This is called upon launching the app
    func getData() {
        someNetworkingCalls { result in
            self.data = result
        }
    }
}

class AnotherClass: ObservableObject {
    private var sharedSingleton = Singleton.sharedSingleton
    
    private var cancellable : AnyCancellable?
    
    func getAnotherData() {
        cancellable = sharedSingleton.$data.sink { data in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            //do your next action here that depends on `data`
        }
    }
}
```